# Adding arrays as Kubernetes environment variables

Tags: java, playframework, redis, kubernetes

I'm working on a Java Play project, and in my `application.conf` file I have a Redis cluster set-up that receives an array of Redis server nodes.

Now, I want to inject that value in Kubernetes deployment as an environment variable and can't find the right syntax to do so.

My current `application.conf` looks something like this:

```
play.cache.redis {
  # enable cluster mode
  source: cluster

  # nodes are defined as a sequence of objects:
  cluster:  [
    {
      # required string, defining a host the node is running on
      host:        localhost
      # required integer, defining a port the node is running on
      port:        6379
      # optional string, defines a password to use
      password:    null
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone please tell me how to pass the `play.cache.redis.cluster` variable to a Kubernetes deployment so it stays like this?

Comment: You can inject your entire application.conf with a mechanism of ConfigMaps.

Comment: Adding arrays as Kubernetes environment variables values from values.yaml to config.yaml . Need to override env and use of yaml function on rendering using helm template to validate. Even learning go templating for index base access can do when array size is fix

values.yaml :
--- 
logs: 
  level: INFO,DEBUG,ERROR
sites: 
  - dataprovider: abcd
  - dataprovider: xyzx

config.yaml :

     sites:
 {{ toYaml .Values.sites | indent 10 }}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can inject your entire application.conf with a mechanism of ConfigMaps:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metatada:
  name: app-config
data:
  application.conf: |
    play.cache.redis {
      # enable cluster mode
      source: cluster
      # nodes are defined as a sequence of objects:
      cluster:  [
        {
          # required string, defining a host the node is running on
          host:        localhost
          # required integer, defining a port the node is running on
          port:        6379
          # optional string, defines a password to use
          password:    null
        }
      ]
    }
```

and then mount it directly to your container:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ....
spec:
  containers:
    - name: ...
      image: ...
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: app-config
```

The app can access it then at /etc/config/application.conf.

Answer (score -3):

You can define any env variable into a pod. For this, you need to update your spec section in deployment:

Here is an example:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container-name
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    env:
    - name: VAR_NAME
      value: "any var value"
    - name: VAR_NAME2
      value: "another value"
```

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks for the answer, but what if my variable is a list of values? How do I add it then?

Comment: It doesn't matter you can add the list of value as one variable, also as  [Alexandr Lurye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9611623/alexandr-lurye) wrote you can add your `application.conf` as config map,

Comment: This solution does not "add the list of value as one variable" (sic) it is simply enumerating keys, each a single key/value pair.  Nothing prevents using delimiters, serialization, or encoding multiple values as a single string (not demonstrated).  Yet this adds significant complexity. Neither is a pragmatic or sustainable solution for large lists.